# Making Cocoa NSWindow translucent hides storyboard elements

Tags: swift, cocoa

In my app delegate I make my window translucent with the following code:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            let visualEffect = NSVisualEffectView()
    visualEffect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    visualEffect.material = .dark
    visualEffect.state = .active
    visualEffect.wantsLayer = true
    visualEffect.layer?.cornerRadius = 16.0


    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.titleVisibility = .hidden
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.styleMask.remove(.titled)
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.backgroundColor = .clear
    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

    NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView?.addSubview(visualEffect)

    guard let constraints = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView else {
      return
    }

    visualEffect.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constraints.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constraints.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constraints.topAnchor).isActive = true
    visualEffect.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constraints.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

The problem with this is that every element in the storyboard is no longer visible. How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all your UI to the NSVisualEffectView as subviews or move the NSVisualEffectView to the back of the view hierarchy:

```
NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentView?.addSubview(visualEffect, positioned: .below, relativeTo: nil)
```

Update:
I created a new macOS project in Xcode and added a label on the view. Then I pasted your code and the only thing I changed was the line of code above. It works.

[image]